# SwiftUI Lista con valores cargados de Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift

Estoy empezando con el desarrollo de aplicaciones para iOS y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema. Tengo una List que tiene que recuperar datos de Firebase. En el .onAppear de la lista, llamo a una función que descarga esos datos y los escribe en un array que luego se debería mostrar en la List, pero esto no ocurre la primera vez que se muestra la lista. Sin embargo, si voy a otra View y luego vuelvo a la View con la List, los datos si que aparecen.
He seguido el ejemplo que hay en https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/firestore/FirestoreSwiftUIExample, pero tampoco me funciona.
El código de la View es el siguiente:

```
private let db = Firestore.firestore()

@EnvironmentObject var viewModel:AppViewModel
@ObservedObject private var subsModel = subsViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        List(subsModel.subscriptions, id: \.id){subscription in
            NavigationLink(destination: SubDetailView(subscription: subscription)){
                RowView(subscription: subscription)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Subscriptions")
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink(destination:AddSubsView())
                {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        Button(action: {viewModel.signOut()}, label: {
            Text("Sign Out")
        })
        BannerView()
    }
    .onAppear {
        let query = subsModel.query(category: nil, city: nil, price: nil, sortOption: nil)
        subsModel.subscribe(to: query)
    }
    .onDisappear {
        subsModel.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Y el código del ViewModel es el siguiente:

```
@Published var subscriptions = [Subscription]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

private var listener: ListenerRegistration?
private let baseQuery: Query = Firestore.firestore().collection("subscriptions").document(auth.currentUser!.uid).collection("mySubscriptions")

deinit {
  unsubscribe()
}

func unsubscribe() {
  if listener != nil {
    listener?.remove()
    listener = nil
  }
}

func subscribe(to query: Query) {
  if listener == nil {
    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] querySnapshot, error in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
        return
      }

      guard let self = self else { return }
      self.subscriptions = documents.compactMap { document in
        do {
          var subscription = try document.data(as: Subscription.self)
            subscription?.reference = document.reference
          return subscription
        } catch {
          print(error)
          return nil
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

func filter(query: Query) {
  unsubscribe()
  subscribe(to: query)
}

func query(category: String?, city: String?, price: Int?, sortOption: String?) -> Query {
  var filteredQuery = baseQuery

  if let category = category {
    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.whereField("category", isEqualTo: category)
  }

  if let city = city {
    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.whereField("city", isEqualTo: city)
  }

  if let price = price {
    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.whereField("price", isEqualTo: price)
  }

  if let sortOption = sortOption {
    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.order(by: sortOption)
  }

  return filteredQuery
}
```

En la primera ejecución, dentro del ViewModel, el listener = query.addSnapshotListener {} no devuelve nada y se sale de la ejecución, cosa que no pasa cuando voy a otra View y vuelvo a esta.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ejemplo del link se ve un poco confuso si estás empezando con SwiftUI por lo que te recomendaría empezar con algo sencillo y luego añadir cosas.

Te dejo este ejemplo simple para obtener y mostrar los datos desde Firebase a la BDD `test` con el campo `id` y valores `19, 15`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Creas una estructura de tu modelo

   ```
   struct Test: Identifiable {
       var id: String
   }
   ```
2. Creas el `ViewModel`

   ```
    import Foundation
    import FirebaseFirestore//Importas la librería

    class testViewModel: ObservableObject {

        @Published var tests = [Test]()//Creas el objeto de tu modelo anterior

        private var db = Firestore.firestore()//Instancias Firebase
        //Creas la función para obtener los datos apuntando a tu BDD
        func fetchData() {
            db.collection("test").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                //Verificas si hay datos
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No data")
                    return
                }
                //Recorres y almacenas los datos
                self.tests = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Test in
                    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                    let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    return Test(id: id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Muestras los datos

   ```
    struct ContentView: View {
        @ObservedObject private var viewModel = testViewModel()//Creas la variable del ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.tests) { test in//Recorres la lista
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    //Accedes a los datos del objeto ViewModel
                    Text(test.id).font(.title)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Tests")
            //Llamas a la función para cargar los datos
            .onAppear() {
                self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
    }
   ```

Al ejecutar se muestran los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Bicho ! Me ha funcionado a la perfección y es mucho más simple que el ejemplo que tenía.