# ¿Como devolver una estructura cuando esta es obtenida de Firebase?, Swift

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, xcode, firebase-snapshot

Hola soy nuevo en esto y pues trato de hacer una función que retorne lo obtenido de Firebase en una variable tipo especial Struct para poder evaluarla luego en otra parte de mi código, me gustaría hacerlo en una función aparte para luego hacerle unit test, no sé si sea el camino correcto a lo que quiero llegar, se los agradecería mucho si me ayudaran con esta parte y me explicarán también un como podría hacerle luego las unit test, ya que nunca he hecho test a mis apps y menos con firebase.

Aquí esta el código que tengo

```
struct exercise: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var uuid = UUID().uuidString
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var urlMultimedia: String
    var info: String
}

let ref = Firestore.firestore()

func getDetailsExercise(withCode code: String) -> exercise {
    
    var detail = exercise(id: "", nombre: "", urlMultimedia: "", info: "")
    
    ref.collection("exercise").document(code).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let exerciseDetail = document.flatMap({
            $0.data().flatMap({ (data) in
                return exerciseData(dictionary: data)
            })
        }) {
            detail = exercise(id: exerciseDetail.eid, nombre: exerciseDetail.name, urlMultimedia: exerciseDetail.urlMultimedia, info: exerciseDetail.info)
            print(detail)
            
        } else {
            print("read exercise data Document does not exist")
        }
    }
    return detail
}
```

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a tomar la función para SwiftUI de mi respuesta en este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469742/swiftui-lista-con-valores-cargados-de-firebase/469783#469783).

Tengo estos datos en Firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura:

```
struct Test {
    var nombre: String
}
```

Declaramos una variable que sea array de la estructura:

```
var tests = [Test]()
```

La siguiente función lo que hace es almacenar en esa variable los datos de Firebase haciendo las validaciones de si la base de datos existe:

```
func fetchData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ testResult: Bool)->()) {
        ref.collection("miColeccion").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in//Valido si la base de datos existe
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No data")
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }
            //Aquí agrego cada dato en esa variable.
            self.tests = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Test in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let nombre = data["nombre"] as? String ?? ""
                return Test(nombre: nombre)
                
            }
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    }
```

A diferencia de la función del link, he agregado como parámetro un `completionHandler` para saber si se cargaron o no los datos; por eso devuelve un `Bool`.

```
(completionHandler: @escaping (_ testResult: Bool)->())
```

La función no *devuelve* los datos, lo que hace es asignar a la variable declarada los resultados. Para acceder a la respuesta de esa función debes trabajar en el hilo principal de manera asíncrona y si el resultado es `true` imprimes el resultado de la variable que creamos al inicio:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fetchData(completionHandler: { resp in
                if resp {
                    print(self.tests)
                    //Imprime (nombre: "John Smith ")
                }
            })
        }
```

Como sugerencia los nombres de las clases o estructuras la primera letra va con mayúsculas:

```
struct exercise
```

por

```
struct Exercise
```

**EDITADO PARA BUSCAR UN REGISTRO**

Según la documentación de Firebase, puedes usar `queries` para buscar un valor en especial; en el código del ejemplo agregamos la siguiente línea:

```
.whereField("nombre", isEqualTo: "John Smith. ")//No devolverá nada porque el string no coincide con el valor registrado por el '.'
```

En donde el nombre del campo va a ser igual a un string. El código modificado:

```
ref.collection("miColeccion").whereField("nombre", isEqualTo: "John Smith ").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No data")
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }

            self.tests = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Test in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let nombre = data["nombre"] as? String ?? ""
                completionHandler(true)
                return Test(nombre: nombre)
            }
        }
```

**Pruebas Unitarias XCTest**

Para hacer una prueba unitaria, copias el código dentro de la función y usas:

```
let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Existe")
```

Cuando el llamado a Firebase se complete cambias el estado de esa variable:

```
expectation.fulfill()
```

Este sería el código de la prueba unitaria:

```
func testExample() throws {
        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Existe")
        
        ref.collection("miColeccion").whereField("nombre", isEqualTo: "John Smith R").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No data")
                return
            }
            
            self.tests = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Test in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let nombre = data["nombre"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return Test(nombre: nombre)
            }
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
        
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
        
        if self.tests.count == 0 {
            XCTFail("No existe el nombre John Smit R")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero al tener muchos documentos ¿la consulta no quedaría demasiado pesada? yo estaba buscando algo un poco más especifico no se buscar el ejercicio con nombre de documento "100020" solo traer la información de ese único documento y no de los 100100 que podría tener la colección, y también me gustaría saber ¿como sería el paso para realizarle el test a esta función con UnitTest?

Comment: Si se puede hacer, solo que si lees tu pregunta no mencionas nada de eso. Puedes editarla detallando lo que realmente necesitas ya que mi respuesta se basa en tu código y en tu pregunta que es la de *mostrar todos los registros*.

Comment: Para las pruebas unitarias debes usar el mismo código.

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón la pregunta esta mal formulada, aunque en el código que subí se puede apreciar que trato de obtener los datos de un solo documento no de todos, pero tienes toda la razón nuevamente la pregunta esta mal formulada, si me puedes colaborar con esta nueva solución te lo agradecería.